# Changing layout of product view

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, product-view

For some products (same category) we need a different layout. How can I get this new layout only for those products.
I know where to find the view.phtml and to adjust is, but how can you select the right layout in the backend for only that specific product?

When I change the local.xml then it will be changed for every product.

Do I have to make a whole new page layout?
And how further?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** use local.xml

You can target specific products or categories from local.xml.

For product page, there are two additional layout handles:

- `<PRODUCT_TYPE_[type_id]>`
- `<PRODUCT_[product_id]>`

For categories:

- `<CATEGORY_[category_id]>`

**Option 2:** admin backend

Go to admin product/category edit page and add your layout updates do `Custom Layout Updates` section.

Edit: (not tested)

Add your layout updates to local xml - with an own handle name ... and in layout update section just add `<update handle="my_layout_handle"/>` Maybe usefull if you want to apply your layout on several pages.

**Option 3:** custom layout handle

If you want to apply layouts for different products or on special conditions, you can add you own layout handles ... something like this:

```
public function addPreviewHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = $observer->getAction();
    if ($action->getFullActionName() === 'catalog_product_view'
        && $action->getRequest()->getParam('preview') === 'true') {
        $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('my_admin_product_preview');
    }
}
```

and layout update ...

```
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <my_admin_product_preview>
        ...
    </my_admin_product_preview> 
</layout>
```

---

**Update:**

> When I make a specific view.phtml for only this category, How can I
>   select the right product view for this different layout.

Either in layout XML

```
<CATEGORY_123>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>path/to/file.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_123>
```

Or in backend settings for this category

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>path/to/file.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: thanks for your respons! Option 2 i now how to select a different layout now, but I don't know how to select a different product view. Maybe I asked it wrong. The way the productpage is shown has to get a different layout/look. Some details has to be removed and others to be added, Like price, description, photo etc. When I make a specific view.phtml for only this category, How can I select the right product view for this  different layout.

Comment: @esther updated answer. was this what you are looking for?